# Chrome and Firefox jQuery issues

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Using this very simple example I can illustrate an issue I'm having with Chrome and Firefox executing a jQuery function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="test">This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#test").hide();
  });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I run this on my local server (MAMP), it works fine using both Chrome and Firefox.  But when I upload it to my live site (hosted at GoDaddy), the jQuery script won't execute with either browser.  Interestingly, Safari works fine both on the MAMP server, and on the live site.  Does anyone know why Chrome and Firefox don't?

The code above is copied and pasted from w3schools.com, which I borrowed to see if I could replicate the issue I was having with my own code.  I was extremely surprised to discover that I could replicate the issue with this very simple example! There are many posts on stackoverflow about browser compatibility issues, but browser compatibility seems unlikely in this case since both browsers do work when the code is run from the MAMP server.

I also contacted GoDaddy to ask if there might be an environment setting that needed to be changed.  The response I got was that it was an issue with my code. I find that hard to believe given that I can replicate the issue with this very simple code from w3schools.com.  And then there is the fact that Safari works fine in both environments, which puts me right back to wondering about browsers.

I'm grateful for any insight you might have.

Comment: Check the JavaScript console on Chrome using the developer tools. This is such a trivial test that I'm shocked it doesn't work. It could be caching (on their server side), maybe extra markup they've added which causes a collision etc.

Comment: Are they modifying your page in any way whatsoever? Unfortunately, we have no way reproduce the error since *the code is valid*.

Comment: There's no error in the code. Provide this link to your GoDaddy support. http://jsfiddle.net/osg9crs4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be the way the jQuery library was being referenced.  In my example the source is http:, but my live site has an SSL certificate on it.  Changing the address to the jQuery CDN to https: solved the problem.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It is still curious that Safari had no issue with this, and the other browsers did.  It is also curious to me that I've had my site up and running with the jQuery CDN referenced with http: for six months, with plenty of pages with jQuery on it, and didn't have any issues before.  Regardless, that small change did the trick today.  If you have a similar experience with jQuery working in some environments and not others, add checking if there is an SSL certificate to the check list.

Comment: Modern browsers often don't like what is termed "mixed content" (i.e. HTTP and HTTPS on one page).